# Football-related short story: spectators incinerate referee

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

In these days of the World Cup 2014, I'm looking for a short story about a revolution in a mythical South American country.  It includes a football match with a neighboring country, and the **total incineration** of the referee by reflective programs in the hands of thousands of organized spectators.

Comment: Do you have any recollection of when you read it? Do you remember if it was part of an anthology or in a magazine? Any memories of characters or names? Was it in English or another language? Even small details could help us find this for you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Per [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Card_stunt#Fiction);

> In 1958, the science fiction author Arthur C. Clarke published "**A
>   Slight Case of Sunstroke**" (also called "**The Stroke of the Sun**"), a
>   short story in which a diabolical card stunt was used to kill an
>   unpopular soccer referee.
>
> **In the story, a large number of hostile spectators aim reflective
>   program covers at the unfortunate umpire, who collapses and dies from
>   the concentrated solar energy focused where he stood.**

You can read the [original article](http://www.archive.org/stream/Galaxy_Magazine_Volume_16_Number_5_/IA_Galaxy_Magazine_Volume_16_Number_5_#page/n71/mode/2up) online here.

[image]

Comment: somewhat related: https://mythresults.com/presidents-challenge